# Best bet for separating fused glassware

Tags: equipment, cleaning

I have a sintered glass funnel stuck in a flask with a 24/40 ground glass joint.

I regularly used this glassware to process very dilute solutions of uncured photopolymer resin dissolved in ethanol. Unfortunately, I believe I accidentally hit the joint with some stray UV laser light while it was wet, thus curing some of the resin, and binding the glassware together:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Because it was so dilute, combined with the flask being under vacuum, I guess it was able to work its way well into the space in the joint.

I already consider this glassware to be lost; it's been in storage for a while and now I'm cleaning house. Still, I figure I'll go for one more Hail Mary attempt at separation before trashing it.

What's my best chance for separating these? Is there something I can do with heat, or a solvent besides ethanol, or some other trick that might help?

---

Notes:

- I've got all the necessary PPE to apply brute force if needed. However, I do not have a fume hood or a lot of lab experience, so things like e.g. hot piranha solution are aren't an option for me. My setup is wood / metal shop, not so much chemistry lab.
- The only thing I tried when it originally got stuck was soaking the joint in ethanol for a while at room temperature, hoping to dissolve any resin; but it didn't work; or at least, it didn't separate with the max amount of force I was comfortable exerting (with gloves on) before I felt it would break.
- If all else fails, then I'm going to cut the top of the flask off and grind everything down mechanically to try and recover the funnel at least. I want to try to save both, first, though.

Comment: Maybe using acetone and an ultrasonic bath. For a day, and with plenty of ventilation. Good luck!

Comment: @EdV That is a *great* idea and, frustratingly, my ultrasonic cleaner is barely too small to accomodate the glass. I'll think about this a little though, maybe I'll get some inspiration. Or maybe I know somebody with a larger capacity cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend putting it in a soap bath for a few days and then heating the joint with a hot air gun or blow dryer. I've done this a couple of times, and it seems to work fairly well -- although it might take a while!

Comment: After you get these unstuck, your metal shop comes in very handy: just make a PTFE sleeve for future use between the filter and flask. Or buy the inert adaptor, maybe! ;-)

Comment: Seek a professional glass blower. While these become more and more rare on campus of a research university for specialized glass ware you can't (yet) purchase from a catalogue for chemistry and physics, these have large baths and the experience e.g., to flame heat just the outer neck of the flask to disentangle the connection. Or contact a manufacturer (e.g., [Chemglass](https://chemglass.com/pages/glassware_repairs)). With standard lab equipment, however, curation *by UV* across glass is less likely than getting stuck by aged grease, reagent alkalinity, or cycles of heat and (ambient) cold.